# 12.04 - Extra default route breaks internet

Tags: 12.04, networking

Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop with wired network connection, eth0 and eth1 bonded and bridged. After reboot

- ping ubuntu.com fails
- ping 8.8.8.8 fails
- access to web server by noip domain name fails
- access to web server by external IP address fails
- access to web server (ssh, etc.) by internal IP address succeeds (another  machine)

The culprit seems to be a route on eth0. This route seems odd because eth0 is bonded and bridged into br0 and isn't used as eth0.

route output

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 br0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 br0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.122.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

If I add a gateway route for br0 (duplicating the second line above except metric=0) by running

```
route add default gw 192.168.2.1 br0
```

ping works and access from outside the local network is possible.

route output after above

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 br0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 br0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.122.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

How do I prevent the route(s) on eth0 from being created? (I note there's another eth0 route in the list. Again, I don't know why eth0 would have routes on it when it's bonded.)

Should I do something to change the metric on br0's default route to 0? (If so, what?)

/etc/network/interfaces

```
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
        bond-master bond0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
        bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-mode balance-rr
        bond-slaves none

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.105
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.8.4
        dns-search xxx.xxx.xxx    <- localhost's domain name
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports bond0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps NetworkManager is interfering? It supposedly reads the `interfaces` file and stays away from interfaces listed there, but maybe some aspect of that is breaking in your setup. It wouldn't hurt at least rule out NM by stopping it.